# How to get value of coolors even thought hey dont have an API

Tags: javascript, api, p5.js

I would love to get the values of the color palette that https://coolors.co generates. Unfortunatelly they dont have an API.

Is there a way,ideally with Javascript to fetch the colors every time an event happens or i send some kind of GET request.

I dont have a server, just a P5js sketch in codepen.

Is there a way to fake an api call, so that I can get everytime something happens an array or object with a new generated color palette.

In my sketch in codepen where i want to get a random color palete everytime one clicks on the canvas on the on the mouseClicked function.

Pen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/aypWOB?editors=0010

```
function mouseClicked(){
    background(color('hsl(185, 30%, 74%)'))
    translate(width/2, height/2)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          amt              initial       range
    const arrayOfRandomNumsOfFirstProbStepX  = createArrayOfRandomNums(amtOfSpotsInFirstProb,startProbStep,firstProbStepX)
    const arrayOfRandomNumsOfFirstProbStepY  = createArrayOfRandomNums(amtOfSpotsInFirstProb,startProbStep,firstProbStepY)

    const arrayOfRandomNumsOfSecondProbStepX = createArrayOfRandomNums(amtOfSpotsInSecondProb,startProbStep,secondProbStepX) 
    const arrayOfRandomNumsOfSecondProbStepY = createArrayOfRandomNums(amtOfSpotsInSecondProb,startProbStep,secondProbStepY)

    //args => element, arrayOfRandomNumsOfProbStepX, arrayOfRandomNumsOfProbStepY, elmntSizeMin, elmntSizeMax, hue, sat, lightness
    drawElmntsOnSomeProbabilityStep('ellipse', 3 ,arrayOfRandomNumsOfFirstProbStepX, arrayOfRandomNumsOfFirstProbStepY , 10, 80, 45, 68, 85, true)
    drawElmntsOnSomeProbabilityStep('rect', 3 ,arrayOfRandomNumsOfSecondProbStepX, arrayOfRandomNumsOfSecondProbStepY, 5, 30, 212, 39, 90, true)   
    //linea(100,45)

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe with this lib https://randomcolor.llllll.li/

Comment: Does it have to be coolors.co particularly? Or would something else that provides a nice-but-random color scheme work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to create code that scrapes the content of coolors.co is not going to be easy, and trying to do so is probably in violation of <s>copyright</s> the terms of service anyway.

You might be able to contact the coolors.co team and ask them directly. Maybe they have an API you can use that they just don't publicize.

Or you could just find another API that does the same thing. Googling "color palette generator api" returns a ton of results.

Or you could write your own. It's pretty easy to create random colors, and then other colors based on that first color. Try playing around with your own program to see if you can get something working.

Comment: Copyright is not involved here. A set of colours - on its own - is not copywritable in most interpretations. You could argue that your _use_ of certain colours, when associated with a brand, constitutes part of a copyrightable creation, but 6 colours in a list? No way. Terms of service is a separate issue: I've checked their terms, and there's no mention of automated usage there at all. That's not to say that hooking a web-scraper to their website is *nice*. and if you like the service, you should at least ask them before using it at scale.

Comment: @Beejamin I've edited my answer, and I agree with all of your points.